# Advance Python Scheduler and SQLAlchemyJobStore

Tags: python

I am using sqlalchemy job store in [APS](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/) . Jobs are added too cron using the function add_cron_job. But no entry is made in database table. Pls help me out: following is the code

```
import time
import logging
from threading import Timer
from threading import Lock
from gadgetplatform.classes.utils.utilities import import_module
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy_store import SQLAlchemyJobStore

class SchedulerManager(object):
    _instance = None
    _initialised = False
    lock = Lock()
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    jobDict=[]

    def __new__(cls):

        if not cls._instance or not cls._initialised:
            cls.lock.acquire()
            if not cls._instance:
                cls.log.info("creating instance")
                cls._instance = super(SchedulerManager, cls).__new__(cls)
                cls._initialised = True
                cls._instance.init()
                cls.log.info("instance created")
            cls.lock.release()
            cls.log.info("lock released")
            cls.log.info("returning instance")
        return cls._instance    

    def init(self):
        self.sched=Scheduler()
        self.sched.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore('mysql://root@localhost/mygola?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0'), 'apschedulerJobs')        

    def addToCron(self,source,time):
        self.log.info("called to add schedular")

        time = time.split(' ')

        m=str(time[0])        
        h=str(time[1])        
        d=str(time[2])        
        mnth=str(time[3])                
        yr=str(time[4])

        func=self.convertStringToFunction(source)
        self.sched.add_cron_job(func, year=yr, month=mnth, day=d, hour=h, minute=m)        
        self.jobDict.append(source)

        self.log.info("added with the time")            

    def removeFromCron(self,source):        
        func=self.convertStringToFunction(source)
        self.sched.unschedule_func(func)

    def start(self):
        self.sched.start()
        self.log.info("Schedular Started")

    def stop(self):
        self.sched.shutdown()

    def getRunningJobs(self):
        return self.jobDict

    def convertStringToFunction(self,source):
        strArr = source.rsplit('.',1)
        mod = import_module(strArr[0])
        func = getattr(mod, strArr[1])
        return func
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used APScheduler, but from the docs, it looks as if you have to specify what job store to add a job to.

You can either make sure that the SQL Alchemy job store is the default one by giving it the special name `default`:

```
self.sched.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore('...'), 'default')
```

Or you can specify the job store name when adding a job:

```
self.sched.add_cron_job(func, 
                        jobstore="apschedulerJobs", 
                        year=yr, month=mnth, day=d, hour=h, minute=m)
```